# textContent for JS without all the descendant nodes

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get the textContent of the current node but not of any of the descendant nodes.  Any ideas as to how I might do that?

textContent does the later.  nodeValue returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a span within the current node that contains that node's specific textContent and am getting the txt for that.  I dunno...  seems easier than going over all the node's children. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if there is an easier way, but you can always iterate over all node's children and get value of text nodes.

```
var text = "";
var child = element.firstChild;

while(child) {
    if (child.nodeType === 3) { // nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE
        text += child.nodeValue;
    }

    child = child.nextSibling;
}

console.log(text);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zqbyE/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved it by getting the textContent of the first child, which actually is the text. The code therefore becomes :

```
node.firstChild.textContent
```